# Windows 10 Run django project on virtual Ubuntu server

Tags: django, windows, ubuntu, celery, virtualenv

I have Windows 10 on my laptop. I faced with some problems using Windows for develop django app. For example, celery library couldn't run tasks on Windows 10. So I want to install ubuntu and use it with my pycharm for django projects. I download ubuntu in Windows Store. But how can I set it for work with my django projects and his virtual environment?

Comment: You need to create a new Python virtual environment in the Ubuntu file system. PyCharm can probably help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without passing by the windows store, here's are the step to run `Django` project on a windows 10 Operating system using a `Virtual Machine`:

Install `Virtual Box`, Download the `Ubuntu` ISO, create a virtual machine with `Virtual Box` and pick your `Ubuntu` ISO, Install `Ubuntu`, then inside your `Ubuntu` Virtual machine do these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip virtualenv
```

Create a virtual env for `Django`

```
virtualenv myenv
```

Activate it

```
source myenv/bin/activate
```

Install `Django`

```
pip install django
```

Then put your `Django` project to your `Ubuntu` virtual machine and run it

```
python manage.py runserver
```

You can also download and use Pycharm directly on the VM